# Iterate an object using SMARTY?

Tags: html, smarty

I've been trying to iterate `{"username":"testuser","password":"XXXXXX"}` in smarty(3.1.29). I need to print those keys and values inside a panel. I cannot iterate over this.

Even I tried with PHP array `a:2:{s:8:"username";s:6:"ubuntu";s:8:"password";s:8:"password";}` I cannot iterate this.

```
$json = {
           "username":"testuser",
           "password":"XXXXXX"
         }
```

```
{foreach from=$json item=key key=val} 
     Key  : {key}
     Value: {value} 
{/foreach}
```

Is there any way possible to iterate over this?

I want output like below:

```
Key : testuser
Value : XXXXX
```

Comment: Please add your [mcve] and explain how it should behave and what is happening that you did not intend.

Comment: {foreach from=$json item=key key=val} {key}--{value}  {/foreach}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the JSON object to a PHP array first:

```
$userJson = {"username":"testuser","password":"XXXXXX"}

$userArray = json_decode($userJson)

$smarty->assign("userArray", $userArray);
```

Then in Smarty it would be:

```
{foreach from=$userArray key=key item=value}
   <li>{$key}: {$value}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks @moinhaque